# OneDrive List files only - not folders

Tags: onedrive

I'm trying to pull down all files in my root folder, using the following url:

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children
```

But this is also giving me all folders under the same folder. Is there a way to just pull down files and ignore the folders? Or is there something in the response to drive/root/children that indicates it as a file or folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should see a `folder` property on each child that is a folder, and similarly a `file` property on each child that is a file.

We have some undocumented functionality that you could try to see if it helps your scenario, and definitely give us feedback if there's something you don't like! The following should theoretically do what you want:

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children?filter=file%20ne%20null
```

Comment: Hi, this filter works nicely for OneDrive consumer (I use it to enumerate folders only e.g. filter=folder ne null), but against OneDrive business I get "The request is not supported by the system". :(

Comment: I just had a quick look and it looks like business does indeed NOT support this. I'll open a work item to make sure we get some consistency between filtering on consumer and business

Comment: Any update on this? AFAIK this is still not working.